# Android - Create a phone lock application

Tags: android, locking

Is there a way to replace the phone lock application of an Android phone ?
I would like to customize my screen lock, and perhaps, if the result is nice, publish it on the market. Would that be possible ?
Any tips ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to replace the phone lock application of an Android phone ?

No, sorry, there is no way to create a true replacement lock screen. There has been some discussion of augmenting the OS to support this. However, it is an area that is rather complex, both due to the code itself, and due to security issues.

Comment: Indeed I can understand, however, If I'm getting you well, we can't even imagine customizing for instance the scheme mod with some nicer animations ?

Comment: @Sephy: You can modify the existing one as part of your own custom firmware mod. However, you cannot replace it via an SDK application.

Comment: You can create your own launcher app for that. Checkout the android sample code "HOME app" for a head start.